# Unable to require the file in the following structure using require in ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have following file structure

```
xml_parse
 - files
    -sitemap
 - parse_sitemap.rb
```

Here is the code in parse_sitemap.rb

```
require 'nokogiri'
require './files/sitemap'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('./files/sitemap'))
puts doc.xpath("//loc")
```

Here is the error

```
/home/vamsi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./files/sitemap (LoadError)
    from /home/vamsi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from parse_sitemap.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is `sitemap`? Is it ruby file or folder or what?

Comment: it's a file .. which is of .xml format

Comment: "`require': cannot load such file -- ./files/sitemap (LoadError)" says what the problem is: "require can't load the file './files/sitemap'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `require './files/sitemap'`, the [`require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require) method is only for Ruby files and libraries.

Comment: Wow! this is such a over doing failure. Thanks :)